# Managing multiple LAMP environments with Vagrant and Puppet/PuPHPet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, lamp, puphpet

I'm trying to create multiple (semi-simultaneous) environments with different LAMP stack versions, to emulate development, QA/test, production, and future-development environments. I want to be able to configure VMs with:

- Apache 2.2.3, MySQL 5.0.77, PHP 5.1.6;
- Apache 2.2.15, MySQL 5.1.52, PHP 5.3.3;
- Apache 2.2.15, MySQL 5.1.71, PHP 5.3.3;
- PHP 7.x.x and accompanying latest-and-greatest compatible Apache and MySQL versions.

I've tried vagrant and mucking with Vagrantfiles and different config.vm statements, vagrant with PuPHPet and different YAML configs, and editing the PuPHPet-generated puppet .pp files to specify versions -- all with varying degrees of failure to achieve what I want.

Has anyone done this? If this is the wrong forum for this type of question, a pointer to the right group would be appreciated.

Thanks!
*rjf*

Comment: Oh - *nix base OS is Ubuntu but ideally would be RHEL, but not on my lowly laptop!

Comment: It would probably be easier just to address compatibility issues with your software code as they arise, rather than building a matrix of every possible version of Apache, MySQL and PHP to "see if it works."

Answer (score 0):

PuPHPet does not support PHP < 5.4